# Getting garbage out from getline

Tags: c++, getline

I'm getting garbage out from getline but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Here is the code:

```
std::string str = "/command?device=c53b1f8&zoom=24&tilt=80";
std::istringstream ss(str);
std::string buf;
while (std::getline(ss, buf, '&'))
{
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Output:

```
á╚╢ºA
á╚╢ºA
á╚╢ºA
```

Comment: Your bug is here: `printf("%s\n", buf);` This is for c-strings not `std::string` the undefined behavior you get is likely printing the internal structure of std::string up to the first null termintor.

Comment: What is the appropriate way to do it?

Comment: `std::cout << buf << '\n'`. If you really want to use `printf` for some reason do `std::printf("%s\n", buf.c_str())`. `std::printf` is a C function, so it doesn't understand C++ strings.

Comment: Honestly, that's only for debugging but good to know! Thx! That worked.

Comment: In general you should stick to one type of IO. Either use the C++ IO stream classes or the C IO functions as mixing the two can get a bit weird when you don't know the ideological and practical differences between the two. And even when you do know the differences, you'll probably still find yourself using one or the other.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. They readily warn about mismatched format strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

`std::printf()` is a C language function, it is meant for C-style null-terminated strings. It does not understand `std::string` at all. Using it the way you are is *undefined behavior*. Your weird result is caused by printing the internal structure of the `std::string` up to the first `0x00` byte encountered in memory.

The correct solution is to use `std::cout` instead:

```
std::cout << buf << '\n';
```

However, if you want to stick to using `printf()` then you can have `std::string` output a C-style string using its `c_str()` method, like this:

```
std::printf("%s\n", buf.c_str());
```